# how to use query_string query for phrase prefix search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have multiple phrase prefixes like below-

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "test_data": {
              "query": "search of"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase_prefix": {
            "test_data": {
              "query": "world in"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to avoid bool query since in my case I can have multiple phrases & 
  also the relation between each phrase is dynamic can be (AND/OR). This type of 
  query can be easily handle by **query_string/simple_query_string** like 
  format.

I tried with **simple_query_string** to combine multiple match prefixes

```
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "\"search of*\" \"world in*\"",
        "fields": ["test_data"]
    }
  }
}
```

But I suppose wildcard does not work with phrase match in **simple_query_string**. Is there a way to implement phrase prefixes query using **query_string/simple_query_string**.

I am using elasticsearch 6.8.

Comment: May I first ask the reason why you can't use the bool query?

Comment: Hi @Val thanks for the reply, I have updated my actual query in post. Multi phrase prefix should be work as one of the should queries in actual query.

Comment: You can have multiple `bool/should` (each with different `minimum_should_match`) in a `bool/must` for instance.

Comment: Hi @Val I have updated my question. Sorry for putting the wrong post earlier. Can you please check this.